# Modifying a BeautifulSoup .string with line breaks

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I am trying to change the content of an html file with BeautifulSoup. This content will be coming from python-based text so it will have \n newlines...

```
newContent = """This is my content \n with a line break."""
newContent = newContent.replace("\n", "<br>")
htmlFile.find_all("div", "product").p.string = newContent
```

when I do this, the html file `<p>` text is changed to this:

```
This is my content &lt;br&gt; with a line break.
```

How do I change a string within a BeautifulSoup object and keep `<br>` breaks? if the string just contains `\n` then it'll create an actual line break.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create separate elements; there isn't *one* piece of text contained in the `<p>` tag, but a series of text and `<br/>` elements.

Rather than replace `\n` newlines with the text `<br/>` (which will be escaped), split the text on newlines and insert extra elements in between:

```
parent = htmlFile.find_all("div", "product")[0].p
lines = newContent.splitlines()
parent.append(htmlFile.new_string(lines[0]))
for line in lines[1:]:
    parent.append(htmlFile.new_tag('br'))
    parent.append(htmlFile.new_string(line))
```

This uses the [`Element.append()` method](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#append) to add new elements to the tree, and using [`BeautifulSoup.new_string()` and `BeautifulSoup.new_tag()`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#beautifulsoup-new-string-and-new-tag) to create those extra elements.

Demo:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> htmlFile = BeautifulSoup('<p></p>')
>>> newContent = """This is my content \n with a line break."""
>>> parent = htmlFile.p
>>> lines = newContent.splitlines()
>>> parent.append(htmlFile.new_string(lines[0]))
>>> for line in lines[1:]:
...     parent.append(htmlFile.new_tag('br'))
...     parent.append(htmlFile.new_string(line))
... 
>>> print htmlFile.prettify()
<html>
 <head>
 </head>
 <body>
  <p>
   This is my content
   <br/>
   with a line break.
  </p>
 </body>
</html>
```